# Every element should be traversed but apparently not

Tags: recursion, backtracking, sudoku

this part should traverse everything but I'm not getting the mistake

```
class Solution 
{
    public boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board) 
    
    {
    
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
            {
                if(board[i][j]!='.')
                {
                    if(!isValid(board,i,j,board[i][j]))
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
        
    }

    static boolean isValid(char[][] board,int row,int col,char ch) 
    {   
        //row
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            if (board[i][col] == ch) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        //col
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            if (board[row][i] == ch) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // 3x3 Grid
        int r = (row/3)*3;
        int c = (col/3)*3;
        for (int i = r; i < r+3; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = c; j < c+3; j++) 
            {
                if (board[i][j] == ch) 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}ere
```

I have done similar question but with backtracking it was working i fid this more easy though

I thought that every element is being traversed but apparently not, please help.

Comment: Is that Java or C#?  You should tag it.

Comment: I don't think this is doing what you intended.  If the cell is already filled in, then you pass the current value of that cell to `isValid`.  Naturally, that digit is going to be found in the row AND the column, since you got it from there.  Surely, what you want to do is find where the cell is EQUAL to `'.'`, and call `isValid` for every possible digit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have an ==/!= mixup in `isValidSudoku`.  Here, I've renamed it "makeValidMove".  If there is a valid move to make, it makes it and returns false.  Otherwise, it returns true.

```
class Solution 
{
    public boolean makeValidMove(char[][] board) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
            {
                if(board[i][j]=='.')
                {
                    for( char n='1'; n<='9'; n++ )
                    {
                        if(isValid(board,i,j,n))
                        {
                            // Make this move.
                            board[i][j] = n;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    // There are no valid moves for this cell.
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
...
```